# in ASP.NET Boilerplate Zero, how does the tenant specific CSS work?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am looking at ASP.NET Boilerplate as a possible framework. Many of the features seem to be exactly what I need, but I need implementation details for one of the feature to see if will work for my application.

On the feature page for Zero here: https://www.aspnetzero.com/#features

there is a feature called: "Custom tenant logo and CSS support"

I cannot find how this is implemented anywhere in the documentation. How exactly does this feature work?

Comment: Aspnet Zero is supported on this forum > https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewforum.php?f=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a demo on https://www.aspnetzero.com then login as admin and go to the settings page (Appearance tab). You can load a CSS or logo here.

To test CSS, create a file, say custom.css, add the contents below and save the file:

```
.page-header.navbar.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Then select and upload the file from "Custom CSS" area. You will see that page header's background becomes red:

[image]

This was a very simple example. You can completely customize UI with a custom CSS.

If you are asking for the implementation, the code is the best thing that explains it. If you buy AspNet Zero then you will get source code.

BTW, it would be better to send emails to info@aspnetzero.com for your pre-sale questions rather than asking on SO.

Comment: the question was how to add it in aspnetboilerplate and not aspnet0

Comment: btw....i tried adding the .css file and it didn't change to color red :(

Comment: and it didn't work because you guys moved to angular & there is no element by ".page-header"